# libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: shared-library

Im trying to use twoBitToFa, which is a small program released by the University of California Santa Cruz, that uncompresses large genome files and I get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No     such file or directory
```

I tried searching for what package provides it. I switched from Fedora which had `yum provides` but when looking for the Ubuntu equivalent, I came across `apt-file search` but when I tried that I got a command not found error.

How can I get this libssl file, and more generally, how can I search for what package provides a file so I can do this by myself in the future?

Comment: You need to install `apt-file` with `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and then you need to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and `sudo apt-file update`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Lets make sure that you have your SSL installed and updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

Now lets fix the naming of the file by creating a link:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

And finally, lets inform the developer about this flaw so he can fix it :)

Comment: In my case (bedToBigBed from UCSC) I also had to run a similar command for "libcrypto" in addition to the above answer: sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10

Comment: In my case i needed to `reinstall` the packages. `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev --reinstall`

Comment: Thanks @EdwardWilde, `reinstall` seems the easiest! `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev --reinstall`

Comment: After the apt-get commands, I'm still not seeing any libssl* files in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.  (Ubuntu 18)

Comment: are you sure that libssl-dev is needed? It shouldn't probably be..

Comment: on 18.04, the library was installed on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Is libcrypto.so.1.0.0 in Ubuntu (`apt-get`) the same as libcrypto.so.10 in Redhat (`yum`)? What's the technical ground for creating the symbolic link? The versions look different.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0.0

Answer (score 10):

Seems that mongo is expecting libssl files in `/usr/lib/`:

```
  sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
  sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

Comment: # ln -s /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
# ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1

Comment: Are these 2 the same? They seem to be of different versions.

Comment: also one might want to see this answer about mongodb https://superuser.com/a/1215357/126616

Answer (score 8):

I am one of the developers of these tools. Our binaries don't support Ubuntu officially (yet). The official way to fix this problem is to recompile from source, which just has gotten extremely simple (see https://github.com/NullModel/kentUtils). We are currently trying to build static binaries without the libssl dependency.

Comment: Is there a new link?  The link above says it's now obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was foolishly using an application compiled for Red Hat Enterprise Linux on my Ubuntu machine.  Merely using the Ubuntu version solved the problem.

This is similar to the lack of support for Ubuntu that Max describes.

Comment: Same here. Not absolutely sure this is the primary reason but it might just be. Fyi - software was RoyalRender.

Comment: yeah, in my case I downloaded mongo `tar.gz` for not ubuntu (another Linux). When download mongo see dropdown list on mongo site and choose ubuntu.

Comment: same here... New to Ubuntu... this answer saved me after about 45mins of googling and trials

Comment: Same here.  `1` How did the others managed to get it to work?  Perhaps they missed the "Ubuntu" reference in the OP?   `2` Why would a distro matter?  Isn't it compiled against the same architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Just install libssl1.0.0 manually:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow got my symlinks corrupted when installing a newer version of OpenSSL. To fix this situation, I fixed my symlinks in /usr/lib64. E.g. `sudo ln -sf libssl.so.0.9.8e libssl.so.10`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding apt-file, first you have to install it

```
sudo apt install apt-file
```

and update its cache

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Then apt-file search some-file should work.

Regarding the package installations, I think you shouldn't need libssl-dev, you need only libssl1.0.0 - this is the runtime library. The second one is for development