# `require': libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ssl

Last night I installed few updates & than run autoremove.
Now (when I try to run server for rails projects) its giving me this error

```
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@victory/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@victory/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.so (LoadError)
```

I tried multiple solutions but didn't work, Can any one help with this.

**VERSION:**

When I tried 
`apt-cache policy openssl` 
its says

```
Installed: 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Candidate: 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

But on one of my friend's system its version is **1.0.2**
has it anything to do with it?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ? Or we will probably advice you thinks you already tried

Comment: I tried soln like https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

& few other symlink things.
Actually I don't have any idea about these things, just trying whatever commands suggested other solutions

Comment: Did you try the exact same command of that answer or did you change the version number of libssl.so to 1.0.2 to conform with the error your getting ?

Comment: I tried same one, now when I tried with 1.1.0 it says
E: Unable to locate package libssl1.1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libssl1.1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libssl1.1.0'

Comment: & with 1.0.2 it says ... Package libssl1.0.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.2' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Félicien are you here?