# utserver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by utserver)

Tags: 20.04, utorrent

I was trying to install torrent on my ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
First I downloaded the tar file from the torrent official website [link](https://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux)
I chose this one `µTorrent Server for Ubuntu 13.04`
And I followed the video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzTBz-tM-K4)
And I entered the following command:

```
cd Downloads
sudo tar -xvzf utserver.tar.gz -C /opt/
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utorrent /usr/bin/utorrent
```

And when I executed `utorrent -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/`
I got an error

```
utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev`
Then I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Then I searched and found libssl1.0.1 is no longer available for ubuntu 18.0 and later.
So I tried `sudo apt install libssl1.1`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl1.1 is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2).
libssl1.1 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm9 libllvm9:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But then again I was facing the same error then I tried this solution [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/339371/1108618)
Then I execute

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.1 libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

And when I executed `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/`
I am getting

```
utserver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by utserver)
utserver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by utserver)
```

I am new to ubuntu, please suggest if I did something wrong here.

Comment: Looks like you've been slamming into an open door. Transmission, a bittorrent client is preinstalled. I don't think uTorrent for linux is a great idea. It has never worked well, and probably never will.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever, I am new to Ubuntu and I didn't know about the Transmission, thanks man you saved me!.