# opening grads on UBUNTU

Tags: 18.04, apt

I installed grads on UBUNTU 18.04.

When I tried to open grads, I got the following error:

`grads: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I already searched on the Web and did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

It did not work.

What can i do????

Comment: Did you install `grads` from the Ubuntu package manager (i.e. `apt install grads`)? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: Yes i used the following: sudo apt install grads

Comment: Please share output of `which grads` and `ldd $(which grads)`. Add them to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1374660/edit).

Comment: If you found anything useful, please remember upvoting/accepting... that is the way the community benefits from contributions.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
$ cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.10
$ sudo ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.10
```

assuming you have the soft links `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.
If this doesn't work, take 5 minutes to read the following, understand it, and tinker a bit.

**Note**:
Even if this works, it is strange that you got that message.
The [grads package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/grads) should know its dependencies, and if you installed via `apt` as you say, you should not have any issue.

---

**TL;DR**

In Ubuntu (I have 20.04) there seems to be no `libssl.so.10`.
From [an old thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory),

```
$ cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
$ sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

solved the problem.
At this point, the versions may be higher.
In my case

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 ago 23 14:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 417K feb 26  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 585K ago 23 14:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 ago 23 14:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,3M feb 26  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,9M ago 23 14:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

so I can link to versions `1.1` (surely could link also to `1.0.0`), or to the respective soft links `.so`, which should take care of the version used.
Most likely, this is handled by `update-alternatives`, or can be made so.

Comment: Dear All, thank you for providing all these help information. Please note that i have found the root cause of the error, it is due to conflicting issue as i have installed two grads, one as a package of WRF and then i installed it again on the base. since i am new to ubuntu it took time to identify the problem. i got help from a friend. Now i want ot uninstall the one in WRF as it is not complete but the one in the base is complete, Any suggestions what i can do??? thank you everyone

Comment: @SandhyaDindyal - A few suggestions on how to proceed, if you mean to get good help here.
1) Describe in the question (or in an answer that you accept), not in comment, how you found out "the root cause". Provide the exact commands and output (copy-paste as text, not screen captures). If need be, also give a description, but do not use this as a replacement for the verbatim text.
2) Specify what you obtained by trying this solution, again, copy-paste as text. I suspect you did not try it, and then you might be missing a solution.
... (TBC)

Comment: @SandhyaDindyal - ... (Cont.)
3) If you have a different question, post it as such.
It is much less likely to get help via questions in comments.
Link this question in that other question if you need the reference.